# UISearchBar и tableView

Tags: swift

Есть словарь на 1000 элементов, который отображается в table view. Как ,при вводе номера элемента в UISearhBar, в table view скролить таблицу на позицию этого элемента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: Int(searchBar.text!)!-1,
    section: 0), at: .middle, animated: true)
```